"口元をだらけさせた" is this a normal expression in Japanese?
彼が口元をだらけさせたまま呆然としている。左手は箸を握っているが、箸先は交差し、出会わずにすれ違った……。
The context is the following: The character is watching someone trying to eat. However that person has a broken arm, therefor he can't eat well.
"呆然としている。左手は箸を握っているが、箸先は交差し、出会わずにすれ違った……"
Dumbfounded, he grabs the chopsticks with his left hand but the tips interact and without meeting pass each other.
What I'm stumbled is "口元をだらけさせた"? I take it's not a normal way of saying?

It's a normal way of using the causative conjugation.
I suppose the confusion came from mistaking だらけ as its own word, separate from the させる that comes after it. Instead, the whole thing is the causative form of the verb "だらける".
Take the base form of the verb:

だらける

NEW斎藤和英大辞典 takes it to mean "to be languid." In my experience, this is especially used for a body part, e.g., "体がだらける" (of a person, to feel languid).
If you say

口元がだらける

This would similarly mean that his mouth is relaxed and sloppy. In all possibilities, you can change the sentence to be

彼は口元がだらけたまま呆然としている。
He sat there dazed and slack-jawed.

But the author wanted to emphasise that the dude is actively abandoning his will to make his mouth "not sloppy". He isn't giving his mouth muscles any strength. That prompts the causative "だらけさせる" which roughly translates to "To make (something) sloppy" or "To let (something) be sloppy". The mouth isn't だらけるing on its own, he is allowing it to do that.

彼は口元をだらけさせたまま呆然としている。
He sat there dazed and slack-jawed.

